# Is there any IDE for java that support C preprocessor?

Tags: java, macros, editor, c-preprocessor

I want to find a java IDE, or any way to config a popular code editor that can understand pure **C** preprocessor (say, '#if' but not athenna comment preprocessor like '//#if') in java code, something like this:

```
class Person
{
#if USE_SHORT_ID
  short m_Id;
#elif
  int m_Id;
#endif
#define DEFAULT_ID 0
#include "some_functions.h"

}
```

Reason: I involved in a java project that has defines and macro of **C** in the java code, then run the preprocessor before compiling java code. 
These code is growing up as a range that I get lost: too many class, members, functions names while there is no code completion.

Comment: That sounds like a total nightmare. Is there any chance at all you could standardize on a set of flags and just run `cpp` over the whole codebase?

Comment: Could you not use a templating engine such as [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/)? And use a [Maven Mojo](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugins.html) to pre-proccess the code?

Comment: For this particular case, why not just use ints all around? I don't see any real advantage of using shorts apart from the minuscule gain in memory usage. I think you should evaluate whether the use of preprocessors is really needed or the previous programmer is just being overzealous.

Comment: What i mean is not about short or int but about the c preprocessor in java

Comment: netbeans supports the //#if preprocessor stuff, it would be a simple modification to change your code to use them.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the kind of "it looked like a great idea at the time" thing...

If all the macro uses are like the one you copied, maybe you can do the following:

**types.hj**: (what is the usual extension for a java header file?!)

```
#if USE_SHORT_ID
    #define short id_t
#elif
    #define int id_t
#endif
```

And then in the `*.java` files you simply do:

```
class Person
{
    id_t m_Id;
}
```

Then when you call the preprocessor you force the inclusion of the `types.hj` file. For example, with the GNU cpp you do:

```
$ cpp -include types.hj PersonP.java -o Person.java
```

That should be enough for not disabling your IDE autocompletion.

If there are other, more creative, uses of the macros... well, that may not work.

Comment: "what is the usual extension for a java header file?!" - why would there be a 'usual extension' for something that doesn't usually exist?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Oh, I should have added _[sarcasm]_ or something, because AFAIK doesn't have smilies...